# how to calculate maximum disk IOPS? which tools we can use?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage

How to calculate maximum disk IOPS?

Operating system is CentOS 7. Which tools we can use?

I have used `iobench`, `ioping`, `iostat` and `sysbench` tools but not able to make definitive statement to conclude the maximum IOPS we can obtain from a disk.

Please suggest tools and commands.

Comment: Found a similar article, if it helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240651/how-to-find-the-max-io-a-physical-disk-can-support

Answer (score 0):

My try to understand "real-world" speeds and throughput is [fio](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio)

Based on simple configuration file you can create different ".fio" files to test what best suits to your needs (take a look at the docs).

Just to add my scenario: I used it a lot in the past to find best disk/filesystem tuning for large backups performance (>4TB) with complex incremental/reverse incremental setup.