# what is the difference between seek and skip in dd command?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, dd

I am trying to read from the disk and wanted to `dd` command to issue every request random and check for the latency of the disk for the read operation I have used seek and skip both will that work ?

```
dd if=/dev/rdsk/c2t5000CCA0284F36A4d0 skip=10  of=/dev/null bs=4k count=1024000
1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
4194304000 bytes (4.2 GB) copied, 51.0287 s, 82.2 MB/s


dd if=/dev/rdsk/c2t5000CCA0284F36A4d0  seek=10  of=/dev/null bs=4k count=1024000
1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
4194304000 bytes (4.2 GB) copied, 51.364 s, 81.7 MB/s
```

can anybody suggest me with any new way to read from the disk ?

Comment: `seek` skips blocks on output, while `skip` skips blocks on input.  You should probably use some [dedicated benchmark program](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108838/how-can-i-benchmark-my-hdd) rather than `dd`.

Answer (score 24):

`skip` (also known as `iseek` in some `dd` implementations) moves current pointer of the input stream while `seek` moves current pointer in the output stream.

Thus, by using `skip` you could ignore some data at the beginning of the input stream.

The `seek` is usually used (but not always) in conjunction with `conv=notrunc` to preserve some data existing at the beginning of the output stream.

Answer (score 10):

From the man page of `dd`

```
seek=BLOCKS
skip BLOCKS obs-sized blocks at start of output
skip=BLOCKS
skip BLOCKS ibs-sized blocks at start of input
```

That can be rephrased as,

`seek` skips n blocks from the beginning of the `output` file.

`skip` skips n blocks from the beginning of the `input` file.

Answer (score 7):

The following example first prepares an input file and an output file, then copies a portion of the input into a portion of the output file.

```
echo     "IGNORE:My Dear Friend:IGNORE"      > infile
echo "Keep this, OVERWRITE THIS, keep this." > outfile
cat infile
cat outfile
echo
dd status=none \
   bs=1 \
   if=infile \
   skip=7 \
   count=14 \
   of=outfile \
   conv=notrunc \
   seek=11

cat outfile
```

The arguments to dd are:

```
status=none  Don't output final statistics as dd usually does - would disturb the demo
bs=1         All the following numbers are counts of bytes -- i.e., 1-byte blocks.
if=infile    The input file
skip=7       Ignore the first 7 bytes of input (skip "IGNORE:")
count=14     Transfer 14 bytes from input to output
of=outfile   What file to write into
conv=notrunc Don't delete old contents of the output file before writing.
seek=11      Don't overwrite the first 11 bytes of the output file
             i.e., leave them in place and start writing after them
```

The result of running the script is:

```
IGNORE:My Dear Friend:IGNORE
Keep this, OVERWRITE THIS, keep this.

Keep this, My Dear Friend, keep this.
```

What would happen if you exchanged the values of 'skip' and 'seek'?
dd would copy the wrong part of the input and overwrite the wrong part of the output file:

```
Keep thear Friend:IGNTHIS, keep this.
```